# .net core 2.2 facebook auth store access_token

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was following the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2#save-the-access-token) to save the access_token after a successful auth, but I have no idea where that `OnPostConfirmationAsync` was supposed to be in my project, I have no `Account/ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs`. I've also noticed that the table `AspNetUserTokens` at the database was empty (even after a successful login).

What I'm not understanding on how should I do that auth?

Ps::I need the access_token to do a few integrations with the Facebook API.
Ps2:: I'm using dotnet 2.2

```cs
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddFacebook(fbOption => {
            fbOption.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
            fbOption.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
            fbOption.Fields.Add("name");
            fbOption.Fields.Add("email");
            fbOption.SaveTokens = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using ASP.NET Core identity with external login .

ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. Applications that include Identity can apply the scaffolder to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity Razor Class Library (RCL).  See document : [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

After scaffolding identity source files to your application , you can find the `ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs` inside `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` folder , then you can [modify the `OnPostConfirmationAsync` to add token to cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2#save-the-access-token) .

Don't forget to modify `OnGetCallbackAsync` function also :

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{

    // Store the access token and resign in so the token is included in
    // in the cookie
    var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider,
        info.ProviderKey);

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
    props.StoreTokens(info.AuthenticationTokens);

    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, props, info.LoginProvider);


    _logger.LogInformation("{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", info.Principal.Identity.Name, info.LoginProvider);
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

After user login , you can get the access token in controller by :

```
var accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Very Much :)